# Copy values from google sheet on one tab to another tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have all my data on tab 1 beginning in cell A1 go to G. I want to copy each section to a separate new tab. For instance:

```
> Route One Start Address 
> Stop 1 Address 
> Stop 2 Address 
> Route One Return
> Address

> Route Two etc.
```

How can I tell the app script I need to go from the beginning of route one to the end of route one and paste that information to a new tab then go back and grab the information for route two which may be more or less stops than route one and keep doing that until there are no more routes?

Comment: are there distinctive breaks between route one and route two? etc? If so, then write a script that will [.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) for all of the routes. Then loop through the routes and create a new tab/[insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(Object)) for each chunk of route data

Answer (score 0):

Add a function in your script:

```
function copyData(sheetName, startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1      = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var data        = sheet1.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns).getValues();

  return data;
}
```

Then, in the desired tab, enter:

```
=copyData("Tab 1", 1, 1, 6, 1)
```